# Reference Error: Property firebase doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

> LOG  [ReferenceError: Property 'firebase' doesn't exist]

I didn't change anything in my code but all of a sudden, when I try to create a user, using firebase's authentication, it says property 'firebase' doesn't exist. The promise doesn't kick in after creating the user. What can I do?

```
const signUp = async () => {
    await getDocs(createdUserDoc)
    .then((user) => {
        if(user.convoCode === convoCode){
            setConvoCode(Math.random().toString(36).slice(6))
        }
    })
    await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(createdUser => {
        setDoc(doc(db, `users`, auth.currentUser.uid), {
            email,
            convoCode,
            id: createdUser.user.uid,
            timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            bio: "I don't got a bio",
            image: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/convoapp-91392.appspot.com/o/4112f225-1b3f-47a3-b2eb-d2b99dfd3996.jpg?alt=media&token=5c8177f3-51f7-4d77-a761-ef6b5c6ce1a0',  
        })
        router.push('/authentication/AddUsernameScreen')
        setPassword('')
        setEmail('')
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        toastRef.current.show({
            type: 'error',
            text: `${err.message}`,
            duration: 5000
          })
        console.log(err)
        return;
    })
}
```

I've tried rolling back my code to days before today, but it still gives the same thing. I don't know what to do because I didn't change anything in my code. And I'm under pressure to push the update over the weekend

Comment: Can you show the full error message, and possibly stack trace, that you are getting?  Also, show a snippet of your code for where you think this error might be coming from.  Make sure you have read [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i've just updated the question

Comment: Yikes!  You are mixing `async/await` with `.then()/.catch()`.  This is almost certainly not going to do what you want it to do.  In my team, we have banned use of `.then()/.catch()`.  We exclusively use `async/await`.

Comment: Are you using `react-native-firebase` or `firebase` in your app?  You seem to be mixing the "namespaced API" (`auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`) and the "modular API" (`addDoc()` and `setDoc()`).  This is likely problematic.

Comment: Okay. How do I handle this? Can you help rewrite the solution?

Comment: You say that you didn't change anything in your code.  But did you upgrade any of your NPMs?  Has your `package.json` been modified?

Comment: I use react-native-firebase for messaging(Push Notifications) while I use the firebase/firestore for CRUD functions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256551/discussion-between-mac-and-greg-fenton).

Comment: Can you include all your import statements as well? You are using the new modular syntax that has `serverTimestamp()` as  top level function.

Comment: @Dharmaraj - see the chat we moved to....a couple of comments above.

Comment: @GregFenton Given how low the discoverability of chats is on Stack Overflow, I seldom join them. Please ensure all information ends up in the question, or at least in comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To close out this topic, there were a couple of issues with the initial post.  We moved to [this discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256551/discussion-between-mac-and-greg-fenton).

Summary:

- remove combined use of `async/await` and `.then()/.catch()` ; recommended to just use `async/await`
- was using both `react-native-firebase` and `firebase` in the same Expo/RN app ; recommended just using `react-native-firebase`
- code calling `getDocs()` was not using return value correctly

[@mac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21297425/mac) concluded that he will refactor the code taking into account all of the above.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing the newer modular API and the classic namespaced API in your access to Firestore.

Based on that, the error likely comes from this line:

```
timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
```

In the modular API, you need to import the [top-level `serverTimestamp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#servertimestamp) function from the Firestore SDK and then use it as:

```
timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
```